Proving the Summability of a Sequence Under Measure-Theoretic Conditions
$\textbf{Question:}  $
Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $X$ with $\mu(E) < \infty$ and $\delta > 0$.
Suppose $\{A_k\}$ is a sequence of measurable subsets in $E$ with $\mu(A_k) \geq \delta > 0$ and $\{a_k\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \chi_{A_k} < \infty \quad \mu\text{-a.e. on } E$$
Prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k < \infty$$
(where $\chi_{A_k}(x)= 1$ if $x\in A_k$, otherwise $\chi_{A_k}(x)= 0$ )
$\textbf{My Thoughts:}  $
By the Monotone Convergence Theorem (applied to series), we have: $\int \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \chi_{A_k} \, d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int a_k \chi_{A_k} \, d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \mu(A_k) \geq \delta \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$.
Given that $\delta > 0$, this implies
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \leq \frac{1}{\delta} \int \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \chi_{A_k} \, d\mu = \frac{1}{\delta} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int a_k \chi_{A_k} \, d\mu$.
Thus, to show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k < \infty$, it suffices to prove that the function $g = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \chi_{A_k}$ is integrable, or equivalently, that the scalar series $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int a_k \chi_{A_k} \, d\mu$ converges.
However, this is where I am stuck. I believe the solution must involve properties of $g = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \chi_{A_k}$ and the condition $\mu(A_k) \geq \delta$, which ensures that $\{A_k\}$ cannot be mutually disjoint because $\mu(E) < \infty$. Despite this, I’m unsure how to proceed further.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

By Egoroff's theorem, we can find a set $C$ such that the series converges uniformly on $C$ and $\mu(E\setminus C)<\delta/2$. The uniform convergence translates as
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup_{x\in C}\sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k\mathbf{1}_{A_k}(x)=0.
$$
In particular, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\mu(A_k\cap C)<\infty$.
To conclude, notice that $\mu(A_k\cap C)=\mu(A_k)-\mu(A_k\cap C^c)\geqslant \delta/2$.

Thank you for your answer!

In your approach, you assume that $\sum{a_k\chi_k}$ when integrated w.r.t $\mu$ has a finite value, but that has not been given. What has been offered is $\sum{a_k\chi_k}<\infty$ $\mu$-a.e.
This is, in fact, enough. Construct sets $B_n:=\{\sum{a_k\chi_k}>n\}$; note that $B_j\subseteq B_{j-1}$ for all $j$. We write: $$B:=\limsup{B_n}=\cap_{n=0}^{\infty}{B_n}$$
$\sum{a_k\chi_k}<\infty$ $\mu$-a.e. $\Rightarrow\ \mu(B)=0$, so, we must have $N$ such that $\mu(B_N)<\frac{\delta}{2}$.
We write $C:=E\setminus B_N$, $\sum{a_k\chi_k}\leq N$ on $C$, therefore,
$$\int_{C}{\left(\sum{a_k\chi_k}\right)d\mu}\leq N\mu(C)$$
and $\mu(A_k\cap C)=\mu(A_k)-\mu(A_k\cap B_N)\geq \mu(A_k)-\mu(B_N)>\frac{\delta}{2}\ \forall k$, so we have:
$$\int_{C}{\left(\sum{a_k\chi_k}\right)d\mu}= \sum{a_k\mu(A_k\cap C)}\geq \frac{\delta}{2}\sum{a_k}$$
Combining these inequalities, we have,
$$\sum{a_k\chi_k}\leq \frac{2}{\delta}N\mu(C)<\infty$$
as desired.

I have corrected my answer to use an Egorov-like construction. Thank you so much, @DavideGiraudo

Yes your approach works as well, I change my downvote into an upvote.
